# Understanding exception handling mechanism (control flow) in Dart

Tags: dart

Assume we have this Dart code:

```Dart
void main() {
  try {
    try {
      throw null;
    } catch(e) {
      throw null;
    } finally {
      print('first');
    }
  } finally {
    print('second');
  } 
}
```

When running this code in browser via http://try.dartlang.org

Produced result very expected.

```dart
first
second
Uncaught Throw of null.
```

But if running this code in Dart VM then result very unexpected.

```Dart
second
Unhandled exception: Throw of null.
```

This looks like first termination block (`finally`) never be executed.

I cannot understand this behavior of the exception handling mechanism.

Of course, we can assume that this is a bug.
But exception handling is the cornerstone of any system.
How Dart developers can explain this disparity?

P.S.

I think this question related to theme "about programming" and asking it here are the right place and time?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an error in the VM, as far as I can tell. I've filed a bug:

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=11758&thanks=11758&ts=1373396821

I should add that while the code is illustrative of the differing VM and dart2js implementations, it is a little error prone. If you feel that your `catch` block is going to throw, wrap the code inside the `catch` block within its own `try-catch`.

And, yes, I agree that this is a fine question to ask on StackOverflow.  Thanks for posting this.

Comment: It looks like the bug was fixed somewhere between r24275 and r24868, so the fix should be included in the next release.

Comment: @ShailenTuli Thank for all. Sometimes the tests consist mostly from simple synthetic (error prone) patterns. This helps finding unexpected behavior. In real life all much more complicated. I hope fixing this problem can save time of others potential users.

Comment: The issue about this problem has been merged to another very old issue (first report Nov 11, 2011). This looks like this bug exist very long time and could never have been fixed.